# global name 'doc' is not defined, trouble withvcall from one function to annother

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, defined

I'm having some trouble with a piece of code I'm currently writing.

With the following code I get the NameError: global name 'doc' is not defined.

```
def createHtml():
    name = input("\nEnter the name for your HTML-page: ")   
    doc = open(name + ".html", 'w')

def createTitle():
    print (t[0], file=doc) #<!DOCTYPE html>
    print (t[1], file=doc) #<html>
    print (t[2], file=doc) #<head>
    title = input("Enter your title here: ")
    print ("  <title>",title,"</title>", file=doc)
    print (t[3], file=doc) #</head>
```

I know it's because the doc is only defined in the createHtml-function. But how do I get it to work if I want the same doc to work when called in a different function? I cant leave it out of the createHtml-function because it will mess up my program since I have a menu which allows the user to choose from the different functions. 
Like this:

```
while True:
    menu = input("\nPress 1 to enter the file name for the HTML-page"
                 "\nPress 2 to enter title for the HTML-page"
                 "\nPress 3 to start entering code in body"
                 "\nPress 4 to exit\n")
    if menu == "1":
        createHtml()
    elif menu == "2":
        createTitle()
    elif menu == "3":
        createBody()
    else:
        print ("Good bye!")
        break
doc.close()
```

And the doc is defined by the name variable in:

```
name = input("\nEnter the name for your HTML-page: ")
```

Is there anyway to get doc from the createHtml-function to my other functions?

Comment: Create `doc` before the `while` loop. Pass it to every function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about wrapping the functions inside a class?

```
class HtmlBuilder(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.doc = None

    def createHtml(self):
        name = input("\nEnter the name for your HTML-page: ")   
        self.doc = open(name + ".html", 'w')

    def createTitle(self):
        print (t[0], file=self.doc) #<!DOCTYPE html>
        print (t[1], file=self.doc) #<html>
        print (t[2], file=self.doc) #<head>
        title = input("Enter your title here: ")
        print ("  <title>",title,"</title>", file=doc)
        print (t[3], file=self.doc) #</head>

    def Dispose(self):
        self.doc.flush()
        self.doc.close()
```

And just use it like this:

```
hb = HtmlBuilder()
while True:
    menu = input("\nPress 1 to enter the file name for the HTML-page"
                 "\nPress 2 to enter title for the HTML-page"
                 "\nPress 3 to start entering code in body"
                 "\nPress 4 to exit\n")
    if menu == "1":
        hb.createHtml()
    elif menu == "2":
        hb.createTitle()
    elif menu == "3":
        hb.createBody()
    else:
        print ("Good bye!")
        break

hb.Dispose()
```

At the end of the day, this is a perfect use case for Object Oriented Programming isn't it? After this, a lot of **good improvements** can be done.

For example:

1. Replace the `print` statements from the function to the outer code.
2. Make your methods testable.
3. Unit testing.
4. GOOD STUFF :D

Comment: Definitely the preferred approach, and the way I'd do it. There's something to be said, however, for first learning to pass variables around.

Comment: @PauloBu That is just brilliant. I've worked a bit with classes before but didn't have the knowledge to apply it to my program. This is some great help! But how do I do the self.doc when I let the user type it's own code in the body function with these two lines: code = input("") and doc.write('{0}\n'.format(code)). I can't write self.doc.write in the class

Comment: I don't see this last code in your question. Any case, `HtmlBuilder` class will work as a wrapper for all your doc's I/O. If you need `doc.write` then define a method `write` in your class and call `self.doc.write` inside it.

Answer (score 1):

Your function `createHtml()` function will need to `return` `doc`, which you can then pass to `createTitle()`. Something like this:

```
def createHtml():
    name = input("\nEnter the name for your HTML-page: ")   
    doc = open(name + ".html", 'w')
    return doc
```

So then in your while loop:

```
doc = createHtml()
```

and then you can pass it to the other functions:

```
createTitle(doc)
```

Note that it doesn't have to be called the same thing in each function.